# How to change Ubuntu 17.04 to Linux Mint?

Tags: system-installation, mint

Is there any way to do it without a USB device?

Comment: Can't , you have to install Linux Mint from scratch. Well you probable could try by changing the repos and with apt pinning, but you would loose support from both distors and it would take longer and be less reliable than a fresh install of Mint.

Comment: There is no official procedure to upgrade to a Linux Mint release from an already existing Ubuntu installation. Even though Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu, they differ somewhat in terms of included repos and software. It is certainly not impossible, but not something I would recommend, as you will possibly end up with a less-than-reliable system, and troublesome upgrades in the future. 

A clean installation of Linux Mint is your safest bet. Remember to backup your home directory.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're very good at installing Ubuntu and its official flavours and (re-)moving other operating systems in the process. However we know little about (the installation of) *other* operating systems and such questions are off topic here on Ask *Ubuntu*. You can ask questions about any Linux distribution over on [Unix.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mint and Ubuntu are 2 completely different distributions *(although Mint is based off Ubuntu)* and there is no real way of installing Linux within Linux like you can Windows within Windows. It would be a nice feature though.

As it was mentioned already, you have to install Mint from scratch. I dont believe changing repos will help at all because i believe when updating or installing software, it checks your distribution and if you try to install it on an unsupported distribution, it wont work anyway. You might even break you OS and need to start from scratch anyway.

Best to just do it from scratch :)